# No material widget found. I have this kind of error

Tags: json, flutter, listview, gridview

> To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget that contains Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.

[image: Error that when I tap product]

And it says:

> *A RenderFlex overflowed by 37 pixels on the bottom*

```
        const Banner(),
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10, bottom: 5),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Kids Plaza",
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 5, bottom: 5),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Text(
                  "Play Station 5 Storage 512 Gb with two joysticks Color: White",
                  maxLines: 3,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
          ),
          child: const Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Haryt kody",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              Text(
                "483166516516116",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 5),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
          ),
          child: const Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Nike",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              Text(
                "Orginal 100%",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              const Text(
                "TMT 9990",
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      const call = 'tel:+9936126483';
                      if (await canLaunch(call)) {
                        await launch(call);
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                          MediaQuery.of(context).getProportionateScreenWidth(6)),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3)),
                      ),
                      child: const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.phone,
                          color: Colors.green,
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width:
                    MediaQuery.of(context).getProportionateScreenWidth(5),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      const sms = 'sms:+9936126483';
                      if (await canLaunch(sms)) {
                        await launch(sms);
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                          MediaQuery.of(context).getProportionateScreenWidth(6)),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3)),
                      ),
                      child: const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.message,
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width:
                    MediaQuery.of(context).getProportionateScreenWidth(5),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                        MediaQuery.of(context).getProportionateScreenWidth(6)),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3)),
                    ),
                    child: const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite_border_rounded,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        size: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width:
                    MediaQuery.of(context).getProportionateScreenWidth(5),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                          MediaQuery.of(context).getProportionateScreenWidth(6)),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                      ),
                      child: const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.shopping_cart,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.5),
                            height: 225,
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    const Text('TMT 9990', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                    InkWell(
                                      child: const Icon(Icons.close,size: 25,),
                                      onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
    
                                Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          const Text(
                                            "Reňkler:",
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                          ),
                                          Row(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.5),
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                                  border:
                                                  Border.all(color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3)),
                                                  color: Colors.red,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Container(
                                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.5),
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                                  border:
                                                  Border.all(color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3)),
                                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          const Text(
                                            "Razmerler:",
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                          ),
                                          Row(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    top: 5, bottom: 5, left: 15, right: 15),
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                                  border:
                                                  Border.all(color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3)),
                                                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                                                ),
                                                child: const Text("L"),
                                              ),
                                              Container(
                                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    top: 5, bottom: 5, left: 15, right: 15),
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                                  border:
                                                  Border.all(color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3)),
                                                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                                                ),
                                                child: const Text("XL"),
                                              ),
                                              Container(
                                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    top: 5, bottom: 5, left: 15, right: 15),
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                                  border:
                                                  Border.all(color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3)),
                                                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                                                ),
                                                child: const Text("XXL"),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
    
                                const SizedBox(height: 7.5),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context)
                                          .getProportionateScreenWidth(6)),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                        border: Border.all(
                                            color: Colors.red),
                                      ),
                                      child: Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                              right: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .getProportionateScreenWidth(12.5),
                                              left: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .getProportionateScreenWidth(12.5)),
                                          child: const Text("Satyn al", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),)
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                          .getProportionateScreenWidth(5),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context)
                                          .getProportionateScreenWidth(6)),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                        border: Border.all(
                                            color: Colors.red),
                                      ),
                                      child: Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                              right: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .getProportionateScreenWidth(12.5),
                                              left: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .getProportionateScreenWidth(12.5)),
                                          child: const Text("Sebede goş", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),)
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 5, bottom: 5),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Text(
                  "Play Station 5 Storage 512 Gb with two joysticks Color: White Play Station 5 Storage 512 Gb with two joysticks Color: White Play Station 5 Storage 512 Gb with two joysticks Color: White Play Station 5 Storage 512 Gb with two joysticks Color: White Play Station 5 Storage 512 Gb with two joysticks Color: White Play Station 5 Storage 512 Gb with two joysticks Color: White Play Station 5 Storage 512 Gb with two joysticks Color: White Play Station 5 Storage 512 Gb with two joysticks Color: White",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12.5,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Maslahat berilýän harytlar",
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 0.625,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                    MediaQuery.of(context).getProportionateScreenWidth(5)),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    // Navigator.push(
                    //     context,
                    //     MaterialPageRoute(
                    //         builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                    //             const ProductRoute()));
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                      MediaQuery.of(context).getProportionateScreenWidth(10),
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        AspectRatio(
                          aspectRatio: 1.1,
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                              MediaQuery.of(context)
                                  .getProportionateScreenWidth(10),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                            child: badges.Badge(
                              position: badges.BadgePosition.topEnd(
                                  top: -10, end: -10),
                              showBadge: true,
                              badgeContent: const Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                '-20%',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              )),
                              ignorePointer: false,
                              badgeStyle: badges.BadgeStyle(
                                badgeColor: Colors.red,
                                shape: badges.BadgeShape.square,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              ),
                              child: Image.network(
                                  "https://gmedia.playstation.com/is/image/SIEPDC/console-right_@1x?fmt=png-alpha&scl=1"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 7.5),
                        const Text(
                          "Play Station 5",
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          maxLines: 1,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 7.5),
                        const Text(
                          "Play Station 5 Storage 512 Gb with two joysticks Color: White",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 11),
                          maxLines: 2,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 7.5),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "TMT 9990",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.red,
                                fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                    .getProportionateScreenWidth(12.5),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 7.5),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context)
                                  .getProportionateScreenWidth(6)),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                border: Border.all(
                                    color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3)),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    right: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                        .getProportionateScreenWidth(12.5),
                                    left: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                        .getProportionateScreenWidth(12.5)),
                                child: const Icon(
                                  Icons.favorite_border_rounded,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  size: 20,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                  .getProportionateScreenWidth(5),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context)
                                  .getProportionateScreenWidth(6)),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.red,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    right: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                        .getProportionateScreenWidth(12.5),
                                    left: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                        .getProportionateScreenWidth(12.5)),
                                child: const Icon(
                                  Icons.shopping_cart,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 20,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ]),
    ));

}
}
```

When I tap product I want to see details of product. At least you can come up with something like this or you can give me example.

Comment: what's your main widget above the put you addede in the question?

Comment: You can use any material widget or just use `Scaffold` at top of the route.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't provided full code and it makes harder to find your problem. First of all the main widget should be wrapped to MaterialApp, then
every page should have scaffold as the first(parent) widget in order to work fine and display ui without problem.

Or simple solution is that you can wrap your widgets with **Material** widget

Comment: I solved this error for solve this just need put MaterialWidget